# change imageview bitmap in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, bitmap, onclicklistener

i have a listview with a picture and some text. I set a onclicklistener so that when the user clicks the imageview the bitmap of that imageview should change. what happenes it the imageview just disappears.

```
      holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

                holder.imageview.setImageBitmap( bitmap);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Maybe your new bitmap is just null.

Comment: @Samantha Show the real code instead of _new bitmap_ parameter.

Comment: @Coder that is the real code, i use  BitmapFactory.decodeResource( null, R.drawable.myicon); to create the bitmap and set it to the the bitmap variable

Comment: still try to post some more code... its impossible to get anything from that 2-3 lines

Comment: @Samantha You should pass _context_ in first parameter of _decodeResource_ instead of null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote in comments that you are using:

`BitmapFactory.decodeResource(null, R.drawable.myicon);` which is wrong, first parameter is null, use the following instead:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext().getResources();
...
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.myicon);
```

OR

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.myicon);
```

and then notify the `ListView` adapter that image has changed:

```
listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgbtn);
    ImageView imgv = holder.(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagev);

    imgv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            imgv.setImageBitmap(bm);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```